# What happens when my initial applied force is greater than my frictional force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

If my initial applied force is greater than my frictional force. Don't I just move forever? Why dosen't this happen in real life? Maybe it is a dumb question

Answer (score 2):

Even more profound, if your initial force is *exactly* the same as your friction force, you'll keep moving if you were already moving.

Of course, nothing beats a practical example.  Here is strongman Azeri [pulling a train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMpwaZ6_Od8).  He is applying more force than the force of friction on the train axles, so the train accelerates, ever so slightly.  You can see that, over the course of the video, the train continues to accelerate, getting faster and faster, as long as he continues to apply force greater than the force of friction.

Answer (score 1):

Friction forces are continuously applied as long as the moving body is in contact with a surface. The friction force is, at least approximately, dependent on the velocity of the body that is moving. This means that even if you have sufficient initial force to overcome the static friction and get the body moving it will still eventually come to a stop as the friction slows it back down. Much more information is needed to be any more quantitative than that.

Comment: so if my force is always greater than my frictional force. The frictional force dosen't matter, it is just gonna move forever right?

Comment: If you continue to apply a force that overcomes the friction (and any other) forces opposing the motion, then yes the body will continue to move forever. In fact, it will accelerate if it has a net force acting on it.

Comment: Initial force dosen't change right? If my force initially is 500N to east and my frictional force is always smaller, it just goes forever. But now that I found the answer? Is it because in real life, the frictional force makes heat which loses the knietic energy, which than slow downs the thing that is moving until it is used up.

Comment: If you just apply an initial force and then let go the force applied thereafter will be only the friction opposing the motion. Therefore it will emphatically not keep going forever! It will only keep going if you keep supplying a force sufficient to overcome friction. The loss of heat is not relevant to the force analysis, but it is relevant to an energy analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you're applying a force against the ground, the faster you go the harder its going to be to apply a force.

For example, if you're on a skateboard and you can swing your leg at 20 mph to push off the ground, your first push from a standstill will create a substantial force. But once you're going 20 mph it won't create a force at all.